# DIV with seperate CSS file in same document?

Tags: html, css, iframe, frame

Is it possible to have a separate `CSS` file for a div in a document. This `DIV` should not inherit any properties from other `CSS` files which included in the page. I will try to make it more clear with the following lines. I am expecting something like this.

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang = "en" lang = "en">
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main_style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div rel = "stylesheet" href = "sub_style.css"> <!-- This with seperate stylesheet.-->
                <!--
                Elements here will have style only from sub_style.css and not from main_style.css
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit: If it is not possible with DIV, can we achieve it using iframe ?**

Comment: Create your own class which is not referred in `main_style.css` and do styling to it in `sub_style.css` .before that  you might want to normalize it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **NO**, if you want to prevent the `div` to inherit styles from other stylesheet, the only way to do is to override the styles either by using more specific selectors or using `!important`, I would prefer specific selectors here.

For example, you've something like the below snippet in stylesheet 1

```
div {
   color: #f00;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

and you've below in stylesheet 2

```
div {
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

In this case, the font will be normal for `div` as it is overridden, but the color will be `#f00`, inorder to have some another color, you need to specify the `color` in your `stylesheet 2` too...

---

If you want to target a `div` specifically, I would suggest you to use an `id` which will be unique, and than write the respective styles for that particular `div`

For example

```
<div id="unique_element"></div>

div#unique_element {
   /* Define styles here, or override the previous */
}
```

This way, using an `id` your specificity will increase to a greater extent, also you can target the particular `div`

---

As you edited your question, if you want to use an `iframe` than yes, you can use `<style>` blocks inside a that document and style that `div`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link a CSS file to a div. But by using the id(#) or Class(.) with proper selectors you can create a independent style for that div element.